# TinyBox2: how to make ajax url relative to base domain url not to current page

Tags: javascript, popup

I look at one really great instrument for modal windows - [TinyBox2](http://www.scriptiny.com/2011/03/javascript-modal-windows/)

There is option for ajax request from another url.

Ajax option need to define url from which content will be loaded.

But url (as I understood) must be relative to the current url (e.g. if you are here: www.example.com/user and you want to make ajax request, you must specify url option as 'some.html' and it must be available at www.example.com/user/some.html).

But I need url to be relative to the base domain url (e.g. www.example.com/some.html)

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work fine if you do this:

```
TINY.box.show({url:'/some.html',width:300,height:150})
```

instead of this:

```
TINY.box.show({url:'some.html',width:300,height:150})
```

Notice the slash in front of 'some.html' in the first version.  That tells it to retrieve something from the server root, rather than the current location.